# #include  не найден

Tags: c++

В Windows конвертации строк использую модули:

```
#include <cvt/wstring>
#include <codecvt>
```

Есть ли аналоги в Linux?

Comment: Если нет, то ищите аналоги. В линуксе есть, в принципе, даже больше, чем в винде для программирования.

Comment: случайно не в курсе, чем лучше заменить?

Comment: Делаю в на языке CLANG rextester.com/LDZZP24517 - работает (как я понимаю это под линукс), визуал с++ тоже компилит, а вот gcc не хочет... похоже gcc отстаёт... (((